# CustomResourceHandler -> Version number is added to resources twice

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I've written an CustomResourceHandler to add a version number to my js and css files, which works fine, but all primefaces resources get a double version number now.

Without CustomResourceHandler:

```
javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0.17
```

With CustomResourceHandler:

```
javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0.17&v=6.0.17
```

My CustomResourceHandler:

```
public class ExtendedResourceHandler extends PrimeResourceHandler {

    public ExtendedResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {

        if (!org.primefaces.util.Constants.LIBRARY.equalsIgnoreCase(libraryName)
                && !org.primefaces.extensions.util.Constants.LIBRARY.equalsIgnoreCase(libraryName) && !"javax.faces".equalsIgnoreCase(libraryName) && resourceName != null
                && (resourceName.endsWith(".css") || resourceName.endsWith(".js"))) {
            final Resource resource = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
            if (resource == null) {
                return null;
            }

            return new ResourceWrapper() {

                @Override
                public String getRequestPath() {
                    String resultPath = super.getRequestPath();

                    resultPath += (resultPath.contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "version=V6326";

                    return resultPath;
                }

                @Override
                public Resource getWrapped() {
                    return resource;
                }
            };
        } else {
            return super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);

        }
    }

}
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<resource-handler>de.sync4.cockpit.web.beans.resourcehandler.ExtendedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
```

Because of that problem I can't get the pe:ckEditor to work, because it can't find necessary resources. Any idea what's wrong with my Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem. I needed to extend the ResourceHandlerWrapper, not the PrimeResourceHandler.

I also have an ExtendedBeanELResolver. I had to return null there if the base object is an instance of my custom handler.